# Finding optimal values of depth and max_trials parameters in vqe algorithm

Tags: qiskit, vqe, qasm

I am running vqe algorithm in qasm_simulator and cannot get the optimal solution.
Are there any methods for finding the optimal value of depth for variational form and max_iter for optimizer parameters? What exactly does the depth parameter?

Comment: Hi @gosia123. What optimization method do you use? Nelder–Mead? COBYLA? SPSA? or something else.

Comment: Hi, I'm using SPSA.

Comment: nice. In my experience, the COBYLA wasn't working for VQE with qasm_simulator, so I thought maybe that's the problem here, but it's not :).

Comment: One more thing: Don't know much about the mentioned parameters, but the shots number is also an important parameter for finding the optimal value in VQE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depth is the number of repetitions of the basic circuit of the variational form. By adding more repetitions the expectation is that it can cover a larger part of the Hilbert space and hopefully include the solution space that a shallower one could not. Now each basic circuit has parameters so it can be varied. Adding more repetitions adds more parameters and results in a larger parameter space for the optimization which thus can get more difficult for the optimizer as it increases.

max_trials is used by SPSA that you are using. You may need to increase this number to allow the optimizer enough to find a minimum. SPSA will always go to that limit before returning.

I take it the solution is found ok on a state_vector simulator, its just when you try qasm simulator that you are having difficulty finding the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got the parameters for the optimal solution on statevector_simulator, but I used there SLSQP optimizer, and this parameters don't give me the right solution on qasm_simulator.